# Dynamics Nav 2013 Web Client Page in Other Website

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

I have found interesting Dynamics Nav Web Client functionality thanks to which we can create Dynamics Nav Page as part of other website. It's cool thing, but how it's look with user license?

Is it possible to create website which has Dynamics Nav Web Client Page where everyone can do something(including people without Navision license)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible - at least not in a way you access a public website, where the number of connections is limited only by the server's resources. Actually, connecting to a Nav server via a web client is not much different than using a Windows client or Sharepoint client from the licensing point of view. In any case, the client doesn't hold the license. License file is uploaded on the server, and the server side is responsible for keeping an eye on license restrictions.
Since Nav uses concurrent licensing model, any user who can authenticate, is able to connect to the server as long as the number of concurrent sessions does not exceed the licensed limit, no matter which client they connect with.

You can read more about Nav licensing on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj551750(v=nav.71).aspx) or download a [Licensing Guide](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=318024)